# Creating a task that limits access to particular folder for 4 hours after it (the folder) is opened

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, eventtrigger

I am interested in creating a task that limits access to a particular folder for, say 4 hours after it (the folder) has been accessed once.

Eg- If I opened the folder at 13:01, I shouldn't be able to access(open) it again until 17:01.

I tried creating a task in Windows Task Scheduler but couldn't find the trigger.
Any help about the same would be appreciated.

Also, how do I implement the same using batch file(s), if possible?

Comment: It may be possible to accomplish this using a batch file but it may be a lot easier using autoit.

Comment: @09stephenb Pardon my little knowledge on the subject but what's autoit? And how do it implement it there?

Comment: After some thought I don't think it is possible to lock the folder but it would be possible to encrypt its contents during that time. [This is Autoit.](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. 
Would just encrypting serve the purpose? I would like the contents to be inaccessible during the time-frame.

Comment: Is it possible to implement in Powershell?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to do what you want (I suspect not). But assuming it is, you will have to be much more specific as to what you mean by "access" or "open" the folder, and "lock" the folder. If a command line session simply does a recursive directory listing that includes the folder, does that count as access? If a user opens the folder within Windows Explorer, does it instantly become inaccessible such that the user cannot do any operations within it? Does the folder become inaccessible to all users, or just the user that accessed it? Your requirement is poorly defined.

Comment: Also, assuming you clarify your requirements, the question probably belongs on SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.